# ? concerning running GUI classes..please assist

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Consider the two classes and could you offer an explanation on the difference between them.. I know the first creates an object of the class but that is not my concern...
Specifically the block of code including and below the line with, 
 **javas.swing.swingUtiliies.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

//also both import javax.swing

```
public class HelloWorld extends JFrame{
public HelloWorld(){
    super("HelloWorldSwing");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello World");
    getContentPane().add(label);

    pack();
    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    HelloWorld h = new HelloWorld();
}
}

public class HelloWorldSwing {

private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("HelloWorldSwing");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello World");
    frame.getContentPane().add(label);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: I can't understand the question (if it exists).

Comment: @MarounMaroun The first sentence...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second example upholds the rule to execute all GUI-related code on the Event Dispatch Thread, which is achieved by passing a `Runnable` with said code to the `invokeLater` method.

By "GUI-related code" I mean instantiating any AWT/Swing classes, calling any methods on them or accessing any properties.